# Аргумент, полученный из консоли, не участвует в сравнении

Tags: java

В этом коде я получаю значение из консоли в массив строк args, но полученное значение никак не хочет участвовать в сравнении:

```
public class Console 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if (args[0]=="word")
        {
            System.out.println("WIN");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаем:

> home@ubuntu:~$ java Console word
>   FAIL
>   home@ubuntu:~$ java Console "word"
>   FAIL

В чем проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"word".equals(args[0])

"==" в Джаве для Объектов сравнивает только ссылки, равенство строк так нельзя проверить

Comment: Уверены про строки?

 private static String foo = "foos";
 private static String bar = "foos";
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  if(foo == bar) {
   System.out.println("Equal");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Not Equal");
  }
 } 

пример для размышления

Comment: И над чем тут размышлять? Над оптимизацией в приведённом куске? Учите матчасть: Equality comparison: One way for primitives, Four ways for objects
Comparison Primitives Objects
a == b, a != b Compares references, not values. The use of == with object references is generally limited to the following:
Comparing to see if a reference is null.
Comparing two enum values. This works because there is only one object for each enum constant.
You want to know if two references are to the same object и т.д. Или Вы рассчитывали, что компилятор создаст два экземпляра одной константы?

Comment: @Dex, ну и почему этот пример должен вызывать какие-то размышления? Обе ссылки будут ссылаться на один и тот же экземпляр в пуле констант класса, так что результатом будет "Equal".

Comment: @alexlz, @cy6erGn0m, Товарищи, ну не вам же я задавал вопрос. Но спасибо, что вы ответили уж. Мне ответ показался не полным. К слову, читали о JSR 308: Interning checker?

Comment: Эта штука может быть полезна, но мне кажется, что она снизит читаемость кода.. могут быть из-за этого проблемы.